# Criando 7 selects com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, sql

Tenho uma base de dados e quero ir buscar o seu conteúdo e apresenta-lo dentro de `<select>`'s, o inicial eu consigo, tenho 7 nomes na base de dados e consigo apresenta-los todos na mesma select box, o que eu quero agora é ter 7 select's cada uma com os 7 nomes, iria servir para escolher futuramente a ordem de chegada, não sei se me fiz entender, o código que tenho agora é este:

```
    <select name='listagem_dia'>
    <?php
    while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        $nome = $dados["nome"];
        $id= $dados["id"];
        echo "<ul><li><option value=".$id.">".$nome."</option></li></ul>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Funciona direitinho só que não consigo duplicar as caixas consoante o número de resultados que tenho... já consegui ter as 7 caixas mas só aparece um nome em cada uma delas... alguém sabe como duplicar as caixas em cima consoante o número de resultados obtidos?

Comment: @Rafael Você vai ter que repetir tudo 7 vezes, dentro do `while` não vai dar.

Comment: @Andrey, mas era para ser tudo automático, ele repete consoante o número de resultados obtidos que não serão constantes... já experimentei também com do while mas não está a resultar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso você queira exibir 7 SELECT's com os mesmos resultados, você pode fazer assim

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'vertrigo');
$bd = mysql_select_db('cadastrosDados', $db);

$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cadastros");

$opts = '';

while($exe = mysql_fetch_array($SQL)){

    $opts .= '<option value="'.$exe["nome"].'">'.$exe["nome"].'</option>';
}

for($i = 1;$i<=7;$i++){

    echo '<select>';
    echo $opts;
    echo '</select>';
}
?>
```

Aqui criará um loop 7 vezes com o mesmo select

Comment: Não funciona, já tinha testado, na primeira caixa aprece correto, as restantes 6 são criadas mas ficam vazias

Comment: @Rafael Eu editei o código, fiz assim no meu e deu certo. Edita o código conforme sua necessidade e faça o teste.

Comment: Agora resultou, muito obrigado pela dica @AlissonAcioli